# How to optionally select multiple values for the same column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, kentico

So I am using Kentico CMS Desk 7 to generate reports for my company. In Kentico you create parameters and then create a table using sql and those parameters with the @ symbol so whatever the user enters into that parameter, it will be the value of a parameter variable like @Status. I am wanting to add the ability for the user to either enter in one value, multiple values, or no values into the parameters, but I do not know how to implement the multiple values. I am a little new to SQL so bear with me. This is the SQL code I have right now:

```
select 
  ClaimNumber as 'Claim Number',
  CustomerName as 'Customer Name',
  DollarAmount as 'Dollar Amount',
  [ReasonCode] as 'Reason code',
  rt.[ReasonTypeName] as 'Reason type',
  PlantNumber as 'Selling Company',
  Status as 'Status'
from TABLE1 as c
join TABLE2 as u on u.UserID = c.DocumentCreatedByUserID
left join TABLE3 as rt on rt.ItemId = c.ReasonType
where ClaimDate between @FromDate and @ToDate
  and ReasonCode like @ReasonCode 
  and ReasonType like @ReasonType 
   and (@SellingCompany = '' or PlantNumber = @SellingCompany)
  and Status like @Status
order by ClaimNumber;
```

The parameter that I am trying to do this with is the selling company parameter denoted as @SellingCompany. Right now, this works for users not entering in any value and users entering in only one value, but I would like for users to have the ability to input multiple values separated by commas. I feel like an IN operator might work, but I am inexperienced in SQL and I don't know how I would implement this. I can't publish the data obviously because there is customer information, but this statement works as it is and I just need to know how to implement what I'm wanting to do. Thanks guys!

Comment: placeholders represent SINGLE values. you can't use placeholders for `IN` queries, without having to build a query dynamically and insert as many placeholders as you have `IN` parameters for.

Comment: what would you suggest?

Comment: like I said, you'd have to build the query string dynamically. `IN()` clauses are one place where placeholders barf all over themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
select 
  ClaimNumber as 'Claim Number',
  CustomerName as 'Customer Name',
  DollarAmount as 'Dollar Amount',
  [ReasonCode] as 'Reason code',
  rt.[ReasonTypeName] as 'Reason type',
  PlantNumber as 'Selling Company',
  Status as 'Status'
from TABLE1 as c
join TABLE2 as u on u.UserID = c.DocumentCreatedByUserID
left join TABLE3 as rt on rt.ItemId = c.ReasonType
where ClaimDate between @FromDate and @ToDate
  and ReasonCode like @ReasonCode 
  and ReasonType like @ReasonType 
   and (@SellingCompany = '' or PlantNumber IN (@SellingCompany))
  and Status like @Status
order by ClaimNumber;
```

Comment: This won't work, as `@SellingCompany` will look like `'Microsoft,Apple,Dell'` as opposed to `'Microsoft','Apple','Dell'`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this SQL function specifically when I need to cast a delimited string to a table value to use with the `IN` operator.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseIDListToTable] 
(@vc_Ids       nvarchar(MAX))

RETURNS @Id_table TABLE
    (ID   nvarchar(15))

BEGIN 
    DECLARE @in_Index1 AS INT,   --Used to store ID delimiter(',') position in string
        @vc_ID AS NVARCHAR(15)  


/* initialize working variables */
SET @in_Index1      = CHARINDEX(',',@vc_Ids)

/* loop through ids in delimited string */
WHILE (@in_Index1 > 0 OR LEN(@vc_Ids) > 0)
BEGIN
    /* parse out single id for processing */
    IF @in_Index1 > 0 
    BEGIN
      SET @vc_ID = Left(@vc_Ids,@in_Index1 - 1)
      SET @vc_Ids = Right(@vc_Ids,Len(@vc_Ids) - @in_Index1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @vc_ID = @vc_Ids
      SET @vc_Ids = ''
    END

    INSERT @Id_table (ID)
    VALUES(@vc_ID)

    /* prepare to loop */
    SET @in_Index1 = CHARINDEX(',',@vc_Ids)

END

    /* return the ids */
    RETURN 
END
```

Then I use it in my `SELECT` statement like so

```
WHERE PlantNumber IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.ParseIDListToTable('Microsoft,Apple,Dell'))
```

This should return the results you're looking for.